# Can't unpublished app from play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish

When i click unpublished give error "you have at-least one active .apk " 
And also cannot  update the app because key-store is lost...
Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried deleting draft?

Comment: try deactivating the apk using Actions dropdown

Comment: when performing that action give error "you have at-least one active .apk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is an old post, I thought it might be useful for other developers who are going through the same problem now. Google provides an **issue reporting** section which can be used to contact them if you are having some trouble with deleting your application from the play store. [Here is the link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing).

Another way of unpublishing your application is to use the **Pricing & Distribution** section under the **Store Presence** section. You will see an option for unpublishing your app from the play store there as well.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: It has changed, this thread seem up to date as per 2023, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555033/cant-unpublished-app-from-play-store

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem today, and I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67573622/unpublish-is-disabled-on-google-play-store).

So in my case I had to:

- Open Publishing Overview tab
- If Managed Publishing turned on, turn it off by clicking the 'Manage' button
- Now you can open Advanced Settings and unpublish the app choosing the 'Unpublished' switch
- Save changes

Answer (score 7):

You cannot delete an app from playstore. That´s a thing that Goole doens´t allow by Yourself, only Google can do that and they will only do that if Your app doesn´t comply with the developer rules. You can unpublish the app by opening the developer console, select the app. On the top left besides Your APK icon there is the current state (must be released or something similar). There is an option "cancel release" or something similar (sorry, I´m a german, don´t know exactly how it is described in english). Press this, and You will be aksed if You really want to unpublish this.

[image]

Sorry for the german language, but I have a german account..

Comment: when unpublishing give error "you have at-least one active apk"

Comment: You must have any mistake here...that error message that You will get is by deactivating the apk...that´s not the correct way, forget about this. Don´t use that option, do it like I described above exactly. Be sure Your APK is still in a released state and then select what I said....I´am adding a new screenshot..

Comment: for me it is a bad thing that google does  not allow to delete an app....it must be possible to every developer....what happens if we just want to quit this job? Then our apps will always be saved by google.....

Comment: Deletions cause legal problems, since history of all activity must be maintained by both parties. 

Just consider your packagenames to be disposable consumables, like a battery, and replace them as required (like when its rating goes below 4 - that is the death of a packagename).