# Want to un-publish Android Application from Play store, Getting error message

Tags: android, google-play

I want to `un-publish` my published android application on play store. I tried to un-publish but getting error message

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):You
>   must have at least one active APK.

Please suggest me how to unpublish it.

Comment: create apk whit redirect link to your new app

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555033/cant-unpublished-app-from-play-store

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you tried to unpublish the last published apk but its not how you unpublishing app. To unpublish app you need to click 'unpublish app' button next to the app's icon.

Comment: In the current version of the play store, you have to click on the application, and then it's in the top menu, greyed out. "Unpublish app"