# Unpublish is disabled on google play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm a new developer and I'm trying to unpublish my app that is in "Open test" mode, but "unpublish" button is disabled. Is there any problem with "Open test" mode. Help me please

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

- Open Publishing Overview tab
- If Managed Publishing turned on, turn it off by clicking the 'Manage' button
  [image]
- Now you can open Advanced Settings and unpublish the app choosing the 'Unpublished' switch
  [image]
- Save changes by selecting the button on right bottom corner

Comment: updated comment with screenshots and the new Google Play Console https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466377/10617148